# Find_by returns first record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

When using `find_by` and just supplying an id param, `find_by` returns the first entry in the table.

E.g.

```
@article = Article.find_by(params[:article_id])
```

returns article with `id = 1` while using `find` gives me the article with `id = :article_id`

Can somebody explain why find_by returns the record with the first id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the `find` method, you can retrieve the object corresponding to the specified primary key that matches any supplied options.

so this is correct syntax

```
@article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
```

while The `find_by` method finds the first record matching some conditions

so you should write

```
@article = Article.find_by(id:params[:article_id])
```

source:http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks, I found that out myself. The question is why it returns the first record in the tabke when omitting `id:`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try `@article = Article.find_by(:id => params[:article_id])`